# Hyperplane divisors: working on an example.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

I'm working Problem H of section I of chapter V of Miranda's book. The problem says

> Let $X$ be the smooth projective plane curve defined by $y^2z=x^3-xz^2$. Compute the intersection divisors of the lines $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=0$ with $X$.

Roughly speaking, take for example the intersection with $y=0$:
$$
\begin{cases}
y^2z=x^3-xz^2 \\ x=0
\end{cases} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x(x^2-z^2)=0 \quad \Longrightarrow x=0, x=\pm z
$$
so I get the points $p_1=[0:0:1]$, $p_2=[1:0:1]$ and $p_3=[1:0:-1]$. So I'm expect to get
$$div(y)=p_1+p_2+p_3$$ 
and it works in this case: I take for $p_1$ the homogeneous polynomial of degree 1 $H=z$, so $H(p_1)\ne 0$ and I can compute
$$div(y)(p_1)=ord_{p_1}(x/z)=ord_{p_1}(x)-ord_{p_1}(z)=1-0=1.$$
I repeat the computation also for $p_2$ and $p_3$ and it's all ok.

The problem come up with $x=0$:
$$\begin{cases} y^2z=x^3-xz^2 \\ x=0 \end{cases} \quad \Longrightarrow y^2z=0
$$ 
so I get $p_1=[0:0:1]$ (counted two times, like in the affine real picture) and $p_2=[0:1:0]$. So I expect that my divisor will be in the form
$$div(x)=2p_1+p_2.$$
Like before, I take $H=z$ so $H(p_1)\ne 0$ and compute using the definition:
$$div(x)(p_1)=ord_{p_1}(x/z)=1.$$
Where am I wrong? This it makes me going crazy.

[image: $y^2=x^3-x$]

Comment: Why do you think $ord_{p_1}(x/z)$ is $1$? You need to calculate this in local coordinates; namely find transfer the meromorphic function $x/z$ to aopen neighborhood in $\mathbb C$ and calculate the degree of the vanishing. Miranda, page 26.  It seems you calculated the first two cases not quite rigorously, but ended up with the right answer. I agree with what you think you the hyperplane divisors should be though.

Comment: Uhm...ok. I could use local coordinate, say dividing by $z$, so $[X,Y,1]=[x/z:y/z:1]$. Now, I get (?)
$$ord_{p_1}(x/z)=ord_{(0,0)}(X)$$
Then? I feel a bit confused, because $ord_{(0,0)}(X)=1$.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. $X$ is a complex manifold of dimension $1$, by implicit function theorem. Since it's a manifold, you can cover $X$ by open sets homeomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb C$, where the transition functions are holomorphic. Say $U$ is an open subset in $\mathbb C$ corresponding to an open neighborhood $V$ of the originwith $\phi: U \to V$ sending $p$ to the origin. The $\phi$ followed by $x/z$ is a meromorphic function. Calculate Laurent expansion of $x/z \circ \phi$ at $p$, and then you will see the order. This is the definition of order on Miranda page 26.

Comment: You're claiming the order is 1, but I don't see a Laurent expansion argument, unless you're using some other fact.

Comment: Everything is clear now, except that I can figure out a polynomial expression for $\phi$, any idea?

Comment: Your question is confused because: a) there are two different points that you call $p_2$. You should write $[0:1:0]=p_4$ , just as @Alekos Robotis correctly did, and not call this point $p_2$ since $p_2$ already denotes $[1:0:1]$. b) in order to compute $div(x)$ at $p_4$ you should use the meromorphic functiin $\frac xy$ and not (as you erroneously did) the meromorphic function $\frac xz$, which is forbidden since $z$ vanishes at $p_4$.

Answer (score 2):

I just worked through this problem (I believe) and for posterity's sake I figured I'd post some more information here. Let's write $F(x,y,z)=y^2z-x^3+xz^2$ so that $X=\mathcal{Z}(F).$ Then 
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=-3x^2+z^2,\:\:\:\:\:\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y,z)=2yz,\:\:\:\:\:\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(x,y,z)=y^2+2xz.$$
Let us study first the case of $y=0$. It is easy to see that the resulting equation is $-x^3+xz^2=0$ whence $x=0$ or $x^2=z^2$, so $x=\pm z$. Then, the solutions are 
$$p_1=[0:0:1],\:\:\:\:\: p_2=[1:0:1],\:\:\:\:\:\: p_3=[1:0:-1].$$ 
We begin with  $p_1$. We can see that our complex parameters are $(\frac{x}{z},\frac{y}{z})\in \mathbb{C}^2$. Further, $\partial_x(F)(p_1)=1$ and $\partial_y(F)(p_1)=0$ so that $\frac{y}{z}$ is the local coordinate on $X$ at $p_1$ by the Implicit Function Theorem. As for calculating the hyperplane divisor, study the meromorphic function $\frac{y}{z}$. Applying the coordinate transformation, $y\mapsto \frac{y}{z}$ and $z\mapsto 1$, so in local coordinates on $X$, we have that our meromorphic function $\frac{y}{z}$ is $\frac{y}{z}$ in the local parameter $\frac{y}{z}$. Hence, the order here is $1$. We can apply the  same reasoning for $p_2, p_3$ and we get that 
$$ \operatorname{div}(y=0)=1\cdot p_1+1\cdot p_2+1\cdot p_3.$$
Onto  the case of $x=0$. If we have $x=0$, then we are left with $y^2z=0$ so that the points of intersection are $[0:0:1]=p_1$ and $[0:1:0]=p_4$. Let's examine $p_1$. $\partial_x(F)(p_1)=1$ and $\partial_y(F)(p_4)=0$. So, again $\frac{y}{z}$ is the local parameter. Study the meromorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^2$ given by $\frac{x}{z}$.
$$ \frac{x}{z}=\frac{x}{\frac{x^3-xz^2}{y^2}}=\frac{y^2x}{x^3-xz^2}=\frac{y^2}{z^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{z^2}-1}.$$
By the Implicit Function Theorem, for a holomorphic function vanishing at $0$, we can write $\frac{x}{z}=h(\frac{y}{z})$, so 
$$ \frac{x}{z}=\frac{y^2}{z^2}\cdot \frac{1}{h(\frac{y}{z})^2-1}$$
has a zero of order $2$. Another routine calculation shows that at $p_4$ $\frac{x}{y}$ has a simple zero. So, 
$$ \operatorname{div}(x=0)=2\cdot p_1+1\cdot p_4.$$
Last, we consider the  case $z=0$. Then we have an equation $x^3=0$, so $x=0$. Thus, the only point of intersection of $X$ with the hyperplane $z=0$ is $p_4=[0:1:0]$. $\partial_x(F)(p_4)=0$ and $\partial_z(F)(p_4)=1$ so that the local parameter is $\frac{x}{y}$. Write $g(\frac{x}{y})=\frac{z}{y}$, for $g$ holomorphic and vanishing at $0$. Now, consider the meromorphic function $\frac{z}{y}$.
$$ \frac{z}{y}=\frac{x^3-xz^2}{y^3}=\frac{x^3}{y^3}-\frac{xz^2}{y^3}=\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^3-\frac{x}{y}\cdot \left[g\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right]^2.$$
By the implicit function theorem, we know (writing $\widetilde{x}=\frac{x}{y}$ and $\widetilde{z}=\frac{z}{y}$) that 
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \widetilde{x}}(0)=-\frac{\partial_{\widetilde{x}}(f)}{\partial_{\widetilde{z}}(f)}(0,0)=0.$$
So, $[g(\widetilde{x})]^2$ vanishes at least to order $4$. Hence,
$\operatorname{ord}_0(\frac{z}{y})=3.$ Thus,
$$ \operatorname{div}(z=0)=3\cdot p_4.$$ 
Notice, of course, that this exemplifies the result that the intersection divisor of a degree $d$ projective plane curve with a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ has  intersection divisor of degree $3$. Lastly, note that this approach uses the fact that $X$  is cut out by $F(x,y,z)$.